# How to read group level values in property file using Java?

Tags: java, properties-file

Example Property file:

```
Label1=DataSet1
Label1.Col1=val1
Label1.Col2=val2
Label1.Col3=val3
Label1.Col4=val4

Label2=DataSet2
Label2.Col1=val1
Label2.Col2=val2
Label2.Col3=val3
Label2.Col4=val4
```

When I want to read DataSet 1 & 2 data. I should get the all corresponding key & values. How can I do this code in Java ? Can you please help me.

DataSet1:

```
Col1=val1
Col2=val2...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**ReadGroupLevel.txt:**

```
Label1=DataSet1
Label1.Col1=val1
Label1.Col2=val2
Label1.Col3=val3
Label1.Col4=val4

Label2=DataSet2
Label2.Col1=val1
Label2.Col2=val2
Label2.Col3=val3
Label2.Col4=val4

Label3=DataSet3
Label3.Col1=val1
Label3.Col4=val4

Label4=DataSet4
Label4.Col1=val1
Label4.Col2=val2
Label4.Col3=val3
Label4.Col4=val4
```

**Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class readGroupLevel {   

    static Map<Integer,String> dataset = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //  1 - Read the file and sore it in "dataset"
        readFile();

        //  2 - Get content of dataset
        System.out.println("Dataset 1:");
        System.out.println(dataset.get(1));

        System.out.println("Dataset 2:");
        System.out.println(dataset.get(2));

        System.out.println("Dataset 3:");
        System.out.println(dataset.get(3));

        System.out.println("Dataset 4:");
        System.out.println(dataset.get(4));

        System.out.println("Dataset 5:");
        System.out.println(dataset.get(5));

    }

    /**
     * Reads the file and store it in dataset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void readFile() throws IOException{

        //  Read the file
        FileReader in = new FileReader("src/ReadGroupLevel.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

        //  Current line
        String line;

        //  Number of dataset find
        int numberDataset = -1;

        //  Content of current dataset
        String contentDataset="";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            //  Find line "Label1=DataSet1"
            if(line.contains("DataSet")){

                if(numberDataset!=-1){
                    //  Fill data
                    dataset.put(numberDataset, contentDataset);
                    contentDataset = "";
                    numberDataset=-1;
                }

                //  Split line "Label1=DataSet1" by "=" and get number
                String[] split = line.split("=");
                String nameDataset=split[1];
                try{
                    numberDataset = Integer.parseInt(nameDataset.replace("DataSet", ""));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    numberDataset = -1;
                }
            }else if(numberDataset!=-1){
                //  Get content
                contentDataset = contentDataset+line+"\n";
            }
        }

        //  Last dataset content
        if(numberDataset!=-1){
            dataset.put(numberDataset, contentDataset);
        }

        in.close();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Dataset 1:
Label1.Col1=val1
Label1.Col2=val2
Label1.Col3=val3
Label1.Col4=val4


Dataset 2:
Label2.Col1=val1
Label2.Col2=val2
Label2.Col3=val3
Label2.Col4=val4


Dataset 3:
Label3.Col1=val1
Label3.Col4=val4


Dataset 4:
Label4.Col1=val1
Label4.Col2=val2
Label4.Col3=val3
Label4.Col4=val4

Dataset 5:
null
```